# Matlab: for even real functions, FFT complex result, IFFT real result

Tags: matlab, fft, ifft

I am testing the validity of the FFT and IFFT functions in Matlab.

I can compare the outputs of these functions to a well-known mathematical fact: the Fourier transform of an even, real function (like a Gaussian centered at 0), is another even, real function (FFT[real, 0-centered Gaussian] = real, 0-centered Gaussian). This fact should hold both for FFT and IFFT.

First I make my grid:

```
nx = 256; % grid total pixel count
X = 500; % grid size (um)
dx = X/nx; %  grid spacing (um)
x = linspace(-nx/2,nx/2-1,nx)*dx; % x grid (um)

df = 1/(nx*dx); % spectral grid spacing (1/um)
f = linspace(-nx/2,nx/2-1,nx)*df; % f grid (1/um)
```

And I make my Gaussian:

```
A = 1; % magnitude (arbitrary units) 
x_fwhm = 7; % Full width at half maximum diameter (um)

x0 = x_fwhm/sqrt(2*log(2)); % 1/e^2 radius (um)
y = A*exp(-2*x.^2./(x0)^2); % Gaussian (arbitrary units)
```

And apply the Fourier transform, with FFT:

```
yFFT = fftshift(fft(fftshift(y)));
```

Alternatively, with IFFT:

```
yIFFT = fftshift(ifft(fftshift(y)));
```

Plotting the results: [image: Shown hare are (a) Gaussian defined in space: y, (b) real part of FFT(y), (c) real part if IFFT(y), (d) imaginary part of FFT(y), and (e) imaginary part of IFFT(y).]

The IFFT does a perfect job: yIFFT is a purely real Gaussian. However, FFT yields a complex number: a very small imaginary part exists. This is fine, since an error should be expected in the fourier transform algorithms, and it's negligible anyway. What confuses me is ***why there is no error at all*** in IFFT? Are the FFT and IFFT algorithms that much different?

*** Note: fftshift and ifftshift are equivalent here, since my array has an even number of elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handling of real-valued time-domain signal is a fairly common occurrence. So much so that the [`ifft` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifft.html) has built-in handling for the corresponding symmetry that arises in the frequency domain, as described under the "Algorithm" section of the documentation:

> The `ifft` function tests whether the vectors in `Y` are conjugate symmetric. A vector `v` is conjugate symmetric when the i<sup>th</sup> element satisfies `v(i) = conj(v([1,end:-1:2]))`. If the vectors in `Y` are conjugate symmetric, then the inverse transform computation is faster and the output is real.

In other words, `ifft` constructs the imaginary part of `yIFFT` to be exactly 0 since it detects that your input has conjugate symmetry.

On the other hand, even time-domain signals are relatively less common and Mathworks didn't deem it necessary to perform a similar test in the [`fft` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html). That said, you could still take advantage of the conjugate symmetry test by computing the FFT using the `ifft` function through

```
% compute fft(x,[],dim) using ifft:
size(x,dim) * conj(ifft(conj(x),[],dim))
```

Comment: Very nice! It makes me wonder if this is true for other languages, like Python or the FFTW library for C++.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your code:

```
yFFT = fftshift(fft(fftshift(y)));
```

should read

```
yFFT = fftshift(fft(ifftshift(y)));
```

The `ifftshift` function shifts the origin from the middle to the left-most bin. The `fftshift` shifts the origin from the left-most bin to the middle. These two operations are similar but not identical for <strike>even-sized</strike> odd-sized arrays. Note that your inverse transform suffers from the same issue, <strike>but shows no error as explained by SleuthEye.</strike>  [never mind that bit, I think I was confused for a bit there, there should be no difference in your case.]

Also,

```
linspace(-nx/2,nx/2-1,nx)
```

would be better written as

```
-nx/2 : nx/2-1
```

given that `nx` is even. It's shorter, but it *could* also have a smaller numerical error due to the way things are computed (probably there's no difference, but I try to avoid `linspace` when the step size is 1.